# How to get this message bubble to be on the right side?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have this as my layout for an item in my listview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/msgbox_self_default" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingLeft="7dip" >

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/pending" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sms_mms_pending" 
            android:visibility="gone"
             />
        <TextView           
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:text="@+id/body"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/message_item_text_padding_left_right"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/message_item_text_padding_left_right"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/message_item_text_padding_top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:linksClickable="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/body"
            android:id="@+id/picture_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            >



        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:maxWidth="178dip" android:maxHeight="178dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:background="@android:drawable/picture_frame"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView 
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/message_item_text_padding_left_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/picture_layout"
            android:paddingLeft="3dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:text="@+id/date" 
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the bubble though to be on the right side. This is a layout for a message bubble. I am trying to put it on the right side like the iPhone conversations. I have tried every possibly thing I can think of relating to putting it on the right side instead of the left. Does anyone see anything wrong with my layout? Please help! Thanks

** EDIT **

The green bubble is the one that I aiming for in this picture

http://getandroidstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/GO-SMS-Android.jpg

*** CHANGED LAYOUT ***

this is so far what I have.. anymore ideas?

[image: Example]

I want the grey bubble to look like the white one except on the right side.

Comment: like this http://getandroidstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/GO-SMS-Android.jpg .. the green bubble is what I am wanting to acomplish

Comment: He wants to have the iPhone conversation style on Android

Comment: I want just want the message bubble on the right. With the layout provided up top the bubble just stays on the left. My other layout that I have the bubble stays on the right like it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Im not going to sift through your code but basically you just want something like this for each message

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="put the right amount of padding in">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="make this your background, make sure to add padding in so that the text view is in the right place, look at 9 patches"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/><!-- Or make this left -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Don't over complicate things, just use a text view with a 9 patch and it will do what you want.

Just swap the 9 patch horizontally and it'll be around the other way

Comment: I need the layout because I am reading MMS and SMS Messages at the same time. I hide the picture view when the message isn't a MMS message and then use the text in that relative layout for SMS. With your idea I wont be able to incorporate the picture as well.

Comment: Put a linear layout around them both and set the background of the linear layout to the nine patch instead of the text view.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Take a look at my edits. Anything else you think? I posted a picture as to what I am getting.

Comment: Wow that looks pretty nice, you should have it so the linear layout inside the relative layout is aligned with the left side of the relative layout, and make sure that the width of the linear layout is wrapping the content.